# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Oracle, SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to drop table in Oracle with SQL Developer
I did this :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees;
```

but it's not working it's giving me this error:
"SQL command not properly ended"
What is the right way to drop tables in Oracle SQL Developer?
Thank you

Comment: I saw it and tried it but didn't work, i got confuse on where to put the table name

Comment: A quick google search indicates Oracle does not have a `IF EXISTS` clause for `DROP`.  [sqlines MySQL to Oracle reference](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql-to-oracle/drop_table_if_exists#:~:text=IF%20EXISTS%20in%20Oracle,the%20table%20does%20not%20exist.)

Comment: Yes I look it up but it's very confusing, i need help to understand what they did

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't really have an "IF EXISTS" or "IF NOT EXISTS" clause for any DDL commands. Just use

```
DROP TABLE employees;
```